# How to switch off gdm?

Tags: gnome, gdm

Because after update - gnome and gdm are not working, and I need to switch off gdm as display-manager. Now am logged in with bodhi-linux ... how can I disable gdm for to log in into ubuntu to proceed there with upgrading and to make fixes to at moment non-working gnome. Recovery is not working because of password not accepted there. Somehow the passwords are not accepted any more due to gdm-bug.

During upgrading there was a conflict with gnome-pixbuf and gtk which was hanging itself up in field of perl-module with gnome-pixbuf.

I need to switch off gdm only. Can somebody tell how to switch off gdm cleanly ?

Answer (score 0):

From a terminal window run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

There you should be able to change from `gdm` to whatever else you have installed.

If you boot to recovery mode as root, you should be able to run the same command after you remount your drive as RW:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is there a way to get into sudo-terminal without need of root-terminal ? I know password of sudo but not of root ... your suggestion above does not help entirely - I need to switch on lightdm or display-manager of xfce4 and to switch off gdm ... and I need to remove the gnome files for to proceed upgrade cleanly - later I want to re-install gnome ...

Comment: @dschinn1001 Can you open a terminal at all?  The sudo command is root.  Once in the `dpkg-reconfigure` you can choose `lightdm` as your manager, then when you reboot it will be lightdm taking over.  I believe that XFCE4 uses lightdm.